# Unable to work with Android on a Corporate Network with WPA/WPA2 security. Always disconnects?

Tags: android, wireless, android-wifi, nexus-one

My Nexus One (Gingerbread) and Samsung Galaxy Tab (Honeycomb) both stopped connecting to my corporate network that uses WPA/WPA2 wireless connections. What is strange is that, both the devices worked for at least 2-3 weeks before both of them (at different times) started going through a strange `Scanning->Authenticating->Connecting->Disconnected phase`. After the last phase, it shows `Disabled, secured with 802.1x EAP`.

Upon Googling, there seems to be a number of open tickets (e.g. [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11130), [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1386) and at least 5 others) related to this problem. Because both my devices were working before this, I was wondering what could have gone wrong. Obviously, long-pressing on the wireless point and selecting `Forget Network` and then re-entering the network details is not helping so there must be some other way of doing this (possibly an application?). Any suggestions?

**What I can do:**

My Nexus One is rooted so I can probably delete any `.conf` files. The only problem is that my `wpa_supplicant.conf` does not have any connection specific information

**What I cannot do:**

Change anything related to the access point because it is not under my control. This problem is definitely a client-side problem from all the bug reports that I've read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, after two months of banging my head, here's a solution that worked for me. 
The following assumes that your WiFi connection is not working but you have a data cable that you can use to transfer files. You may not have the exact screen as shown in the screenshots. That's because I am using a different ROM for my device but the overall steps will not change.

#### Step 1: Get an alternate WiFi configuration editor

- I used WiFi Advanced Configuration Editor, which is an open source project available [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-ace/). Install from the Android Market [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.marcus905.wifi.ace)

#### Step 2: Modify the WiFi settings

- Open WiFi Advanced Configuration Editor
- Select your WiFi network
- Select `Key Management`

[image]

- You will probably see that `WPA_EAP` and `IEEE8021X` are set to `Enabled` or `ON`. Let `WPA_EAP` stay as it is but turn off `IEEE8021X`. In the end, it should look like the following:

[image]

- Hit the `Back` button on your device to go back one screen. **DO NOT QUIT THE APPLICATION YET!**

#### Step 3: Re-enter your password

- In the screen that you selected `Key Management` from, select `Enterprise Configuration`.

[image]

- Select `Password` and enter your password and hit `OK` to save it
- Hit the `Back` button on your device three times to exit the application.

And that's it! If it works, congratulations and welcome to the `bug-skipped` bandwagon. If it didn't, sorry for taking your time. But hopefully, Google will fix this nasty bug soon.